# Weird substitution failure with C++11 variadic template

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I'm having a hard time figuring out what causes the substitution failure in this example code:

```
bool f(int a, int b, float c)
{
    printf("%d %d %f", a, b, c);
    return true;
}

template <typename ...Params>
void call1(Params... params, std::function<bool(Params...)> func)
{
    func(params...);
}

template <typename ...Params>
void call2(std::function<bool(Params...)> func)
{
}
```

Somewhere in main:

```
call1<int, int, float>(3, 4, 5.5, f); // Ok.
call2<int, int, float>(f); // Substitution failure.
```

The compiler says:

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed: mismatched types 'std::function<bool(Params ...)>' and 'bool (*)(int, int, float)'
call2<int, int, float>(f);
                          ^
```

What baffles me is that call1 works while call2 doesn't.
Any tips? =)

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but clang++ give the following message: `note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<bool (int, int, float, type-parameter-0-0...)>' against 'bool (*)(int, int, float)'`. Here you can see that there is an extra `type-parameter-0-0...` argument that is the likely culprit. How to get rid of it I don't know.

Comment: I don't get the logic of this, are you trying to call f without parameters while giving 3 types to your template ?

Comment: I still don't get what you are trying to do but I think that your `f` in call2 is interpreted as an int ( the address of the function f is the value of that `int` ) thus leaving the second `int`, the `float` and the `func` argument of your template "undefined" and no match is possible in this case.

Comment: I am not trying to call f at all. This is a minimal example demonstrating a problem. The motivation for this was making a function that automatically converts a list of strings into the proper arguments and passes them to func. I've solved the original problem by passing a callable template parameter instead of an std::function, but I still want to solve this mystery. As for your theory, the compiler error implies otherwise.

Comment: -1 for not including compiler and version in the post, as that makes a huge difference. Certain common compilers (VC11 and below) don't really support variadics and simulate them in some cases. It may not be essential to the solution but it gives people a place to start, and lets us know what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: You can specify less arguments than what you use and let the compiler deduce the rest:

```
template <typename ...Params>
void func1(Params... params);

func1<int, int>(1, 2, 3); // calls func1<int, int, int>
```

This means `Params` is still open for adding extra types when you call it. But if you take the function address, it becomes defined and closed:

```
auto x = func1<int, int>;
x(1, 2, 3); // not possible
```

When you call your `call1` function directly:

```
template <typename... Params>
void call1(Params... params, std::function<bool(Params...)> func);

call1<int, int, int>(1, 2, 3, f);
call1<int>(1, 2, 3, f); // same as before
call1(1, 2, 3, f); // same as before
```

The compiler is able to deduce that you have exactly 3 ints because you just sent him 3 ints. This way the last parameter must be `std::function<bool(int, int, int)>` because we fully deduced what `Params...` means and there's no space for more types.

Now the problematic case:

```
template <typename... Params>
void call2(std::function<bool(Params...)> func);

call2<int, int, int>(f);
```

Here you informed the compiler that the first 3 elements of `Params` are all ints. `Params = {int, int, int, ...}`. Note that it is still open for adding something else if deduction tells so. Replacing we have: `std::function<bool(int, int, int, ...)> func`. The compiler can't possibly know what this incomplete type means unless you explicitly pass a `std:function` (exact match). It doesn't know yet it can have a constructor taking the function pointer you provided, so there's a mismatch. Now the compiler does not have enough data to decide if it need more types into `Params` or not. Failure.

But note this interesting case:

```
auto x = call2<int, int, int>;
x(f); // x is exactly void(*)(std::function<bool(int, int, int)>). No doubts.
```

Here the you force `Params` to be complete. There's no deduction to evaluate. Although ugly, this also works:

```
(&call2<int, int, int>)(f);
```

Comment: Regarding "can't possible know what this incomplete type means" that's what deduction is for, you have no problems calling `call2<int,int,float>(std::function<bool(int,int,float)>(f))` the parameter type is deduced from the argument type and there's no *need* to perform implicit conversion like in the case when passing a plain function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can't deduce the type with your current code (even though the function pointer is implicitly convertible to a `std::function`). You could create a traits class to help deduce the correct type.

```
template <typename... Params>
struct func_traits {
    using func_type = std::function<bool(Params...)>;
};

template <typename ...Params>
void call2(typename func_traits<Params...>::func_type func) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of the expression `f` is a pointer to function, i.e. `bool (*)(int, int, float)`. Yet the explicit instantiation of `call2` template has type `void foo (std::function<bool (int, int, float)> )`, i.e. the parameter type is different, hence the mismatch.

Workaround:

```
auto x = call2<int, int, float>;
x(f);
```

taking advantage of the possibility to construct a `std::function` from a function pointer.

Comment: The parameter `std::function<bool (int,int,float)>` has a deduced type, hence it "contains template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction" and the implicit conversions are not performed when matching function argument to function parameter (14.8.1 #6).